# I have 3 tables Flight_schedule, Flights and third is Route I need a stored procedure in SQL which give the cheapest flight on a given date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables Flight_schedule, Flights and third is Route I need a stored procedure in SQL which give the cheapest flight on a given date.

When the parameter date is passed to procedure suppose 2 February so the result would be the lowest fare flight on the 2 Feb.

Here is the code where I have joined the tables and passed the parameter to stored procedure but when I am confused in the condition part.

```
Create proc spCheapestFlight 
@FLIGHT_DATE DATE 
AS  
BEGIN  
SELECT Flight_schedule.FlightDate,Flight_schedule.Departure,route.source, route.destination, 
    Flight_schedule.Arrival 
    ,Flight_schedule.Fare,Flights.Flight_name 
    FROM Flight_schedule 
    inner join route ON Flight_schedule.Route_id=route.Route_id inner join  
Flights on Flights.Flight_id=Flight_schedule.Flight_id 
where Flight_schedule.FlightDate = @FLIGHT_DATE   
END
```

Comment: Please add tabular data using markdown rather than adding images

Comment: Can you please add what is the expected output for the given data. What did you try doing? Where are you stuck?

Comment: And don't use images, format the data as text

Comment: And explain the logic of how the cheapest flight would be determined from the provided data.

Comment: So what are you confused about? What should the results look like?

Comment: sorry for bad edit actually this is first time I have posted any question @DaleK

Comment: Is this question about the real world or just a learning exercise? You seem to assume only direct paths are considered. And your procedure name is very inaccurate if you seek cheapest flight. Code should not lie about what it does. Good and accurate names are important - as is some attempt on your part to format your code to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

Flight_schedule

| F_Id | Flight_id | Total_Fare | FlightDate | Departure | Arrival | Route_Id | Fare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10000 | 1 | 1001 | 2022-02-01 | 09:30:30.0000000 | 11:20:45.0000000 | 100 | 7500.8 |
| 10001 | 2 | 1002 | 2022-02-02 | 09:45:30.0000000 | 11:55:45.0000000 | 101 | 7000.9 |
| 10002 | 3 | 1003 | 2022-02-03 | 10:30:30.0000000 | 12:20:45.0000000 | 102 | 5111.5 |
| 10003 | 4 | 1004 | 2022-02-04 | 11:30:30.0000000 | 14:20:45.0000000 | 103 | 5500.9 |
| 10004 | 5 | 1005 | 2022-02-05 | 12:30:30.0000000 | 15:20:45.0000000 | 104 | 9000.7 |
| 10005 | 1 | 1006 | 2022-02-06 | 13:30:30.0000000 | 16:20:45.0000000 | 105 | 8675.5 |
| 10006 | 2 | 1007 | 2022-02-07 | 14:30:30.0000000 | 17:20:45.0000000 | 106 | 4000.5 |
| 10007 | 3 | 1008 | 2022-02-08 | 15:30:30.0000000 | 18:20:45.0000000 | 107 | 4100.5 |
| 10008 | 4 | 1009 | 2022-02-09 | 16:30:30.0000000 | 19:20:45.0000000 | 101 | 4000.3 |
| 10009 | 2 | 1006 | 2022-02-10 | 06:30:30.0000000 | 08:20:45.0000000 | 108 | 4000.3 |

Flights

| Flight_id | Flight_name | Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Vistara | 30 |
| 2 | Indigo | 30 |
| 3 | SpiceJet | 30 |
| 4 | Go_First | 30 |
| 5 | Air India | 30 |

Route

| route_id | source | destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | Mumbai | Delhi |
| 101 | Delhi | Ahmedabad |
| 102 | Ahmedabad | Delhi |
| 103 | Ahmedabad | Mumbai |
| 104 | Chennai | Mumbai |
| 105 | Chennai | Goa |
| 106 | Chennai | Delhi |
| 107 | Goa | Delhi |
| 108 | Bangalore | Delhi |
| 109 | Hyderabad | Delhi |

your data does not show more than 1 flight per day, in addition there is no need for **table Flights** and **table Route** to get result, you should join table FlightSchedule with itself in order to get the minimum fare. your problem can be solve with table-value function(TVF). you should change you PROCEDURE as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  spCheapest_Costliest_Flight (@FlightDate DATE) 
AS    
SELECT FS.FlightDate,FS.Departure,route.source, route.destination, 
FS.Arrival ,T.Fare,Flights.Flight_name 
FROM Flight_schedule FS
inner join route ON FS.Route_id=route.Route_id 
inner join Flights on Flights.Flight_id=FS.Flight_id 
inner join  (select FlightDate FlightDate,MIN(Fare) Fare
from Flight_schedule GROUP BY FlightDate) T
ON T.FlightDate=FS.FlightDate and T.FlightDate=@FlightDate and FS.FlightDate=@FlightDate
GO
```